# Why can I not cast this cell to a class that inherits from cell in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am creating a `TableView` in swift using the `UITableViewCOntroller`, which I have done in several other apps, however this time when I try to cast my cell to the custom cell class I get the error that it cannot be cast.

Here is my code:

```
class CollapseNoteViewController: UITableViewController {

    let titleArray = ["Troy and Abed", "Shirly and Annie", "Pierce and Ben"]
    let noteArray = ["The best", "Pretty cool", "The worst"]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return titleArray.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        // This is where I get the error
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: K.reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! NoteTableViewCell 
        
        cell.titleLabel?.text = titleArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel?.text = noteArray[indexPath.row]
        
        return cell
    }
    
}

class NoteTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var cardView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var titleLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainTextLabel: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }
    
}
```

The full error text:

```
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1eccdbb70) to 'CollapseANote.NoteTableViewCell' (0x104d3ced8).
Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1eccdbb70) to 'CollapseANote.NoteTableViewCell' (0x104d3ced8).
2021-02-18 10:36:47.613801-0500 CollapseANote[639:74162] Could not cast value of type 'UITableViewCell' (0x1eccdbb70) to 'CollapseANote.NoteTableViewCell' (0x104d3ced8).
```

Where I set the class for the prototype cell:

[image]

Where I set the class for `TableViewController`:

[image]

Comment: Set the class of the custom cell in Interface Builder to `NoteTableViewCell`

Comment: @vadian, I have done that but I still get this error

Comment: The error clearly says that the dequeued cell is `UITableViewCell`, the base class. And never use multiple arrays for the data source. That's very bad practice.

Comment: if so then you don't set the base class properly make sure to put cursor above name and click enter may be the target is wrong , some times the class name is here but the target is wrong

Comment: make sure inherit module from target is ticked

Comment: According to your last image may be you need to set the class name also `CollapseNoteViewController` ? Verify it ?

Comment: I have also done that

Comment: can you share a github demo ?

Comment: https://github.com/DavidBrynnHouse/CollapseANote

Comment: You are assigning UITableViewCell class name to UIView object in storyboard. It will certainly crash. Set class name in the tableviewcell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You nest to table cells and set the class name to the inner one that's why ist's not visible here

[image]

Drag the inner one to out like

[image]

Then delete the NoteItemCell

[image]

It's up to you to leave it if it represents another different cell

Comment: Would this work in the case where I have not created a separate nib file? In this project I just added elements to the prototype cell of the ```UITableViewController```.